# How can I set a background color for a general element and then set the background color of a specific element (same kind) with one event(onclick)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this UltraTicTacToe Game I am coding with HTML/CSS/JS. It is made with tables within tables within a table. When you click either X or O I want the next TicTacToe table/game you are supposed to go in to highlight. I want to reset the highlighted table/game back to white and highlight another table/game. I am currently trying to do this by using a function to set the background color of all tables to white and then the specific one to yellow, but it is refusing to work for me... Any ideas?

```js
function tableReset() {
  document.getElementByClassName('tabler').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}

function hide1() {
  document.getElementById('o1').style.display = 'none';
}

function reSize1() {
  document.getElementById('x1').style.width = '100%';
}

function nextMove1() {
  document.getElementById('st1').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
```

```html
<table class="tabler" id="st1">
  <tr class="topmid">
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="x" id="x1" onclick="hide1(); reSize1(); tableReset(); nextMove1();">X</button>
      <button type="button" class="o" id="o1" onclick="hide2(); reSize2(); tableReset(); nextMove1();">O</button>
    </td>
```

[Here is a pic of the game look - UltraTICTACTOE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aomGv.png)

Comment: toggle a class....

Comment: `document.getElementByClassName()` returns a `NodeList`, not a single element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`. You can get its first element using `document.getElementsByClassName('tabler')[0]` or you can use `getElementById`.

```js
function tableReset() {
  //document.getElementsByClassName('tabler')[0].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  //or
  document.getElementById('st1').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
}

function hide1() {
  document.getElementById('x1').style.display = 'none';
}
function hide2() {
  document.getElementById('o1').style.display = 'none';
}
function reSize1() {
  document.getElementById('x1').style.width = '100%';
}
function reSize2() {
  document.getElementById('o1').style.width = '100%';
}

function nextMove1() {
  document.getElementById('st1').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
```

```html
<table class="tabler" id="st1">
  <tr class="topmid">
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="x" id="x1" onclick="hide1(); reSize1(); tableReset(); nextMove1();">X</button>
      <button type="button" class="o" id="o1" onclick="hide2(); reSize2(); tableReset(); nextMove1();">O</button>
    </td>
```

Comment: So is there any way to select all the tables?

Comment: This is what I ended up using and it works! Thanks for your help!        var myNodelist = document.querySelectorAll("table");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
    myNodelist[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

Comment: That's fine, remember you will get all the table elements of your document.

Answer (score 0):

This selects them all if anyone else runs into this question!

```js
var myNodelist = document.querySelectorAll("table");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
    myNodelist[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```